# Still cannot connect Tomcat 6 remotely via VisualVM

Tags: java, tomcat, monitoring, tomcat6, visualvm

If checked the other questions regarding this issue but so far no soultion.
Here is my setup:
TC6 runs on a debian vm on my macbook. in /etc/default/tomcat6.0 I have following options set:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

netstat -ntlp gives me:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      6550/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                    LISTEN      6550/java
```

Where 6550:

```
root      6550  3.3  6.8 224888 52984 pts/0    Sl   10:31   0:43 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6.0/conf/logging.properties -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6.0/common/endorsed -classpath :/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre//lib/jcert.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre//lib/jnet.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre//lib/jsse.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6.0/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6.0/bin/commons-logging-api.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6.0 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6.0 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/tomcat6.0/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Firewall:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere
```

When I try to connect from OSX using jvisualm:
- adding a new host with the hostname of my vm (added it to /etc/hosts)
- adding a new JMX-Connection

VisualVM fails with:

```
Cannot connect using service:jmx:rmi///jndi/rmi://<vmhostname>:8086/jmxrmi
```

When I connect to my VM using `ssh -X` and start jvisualvm on the same machine that tomcat is running on, I do not initially see TC, but I can add the jmx connection as above.

Could this be an issue with foreign hosts being misteriously prevented to access the rmiregistry? 
Why would anyone do such a dumb thing?

What am I doing wrong?

(sorry 4 the lengthy post)

Comment: RMI opens other, dynamic ports as well (and the default JMX connection uses RMI). That makes it a pain to tunnel and to correctly configure a firewall. Basically it was never designed to run anywhere but a wide-open network. Since I can't give any concrete details, I just wrote this comment.

Comment: Thank you Joachim. Actually the firewalling stuff is what puzzles me. Since it runs on a VM on my local machine I have completely disabled firewalling see above (ACCEPT ALL).

You state, that using rmi is the default. Do you have any other ideas how to monitor a remote tomcat with visualvm?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a tutorial on [how to connect Visual VM to Tomcat 7](http://blog.markwshead.com/1129/connecting-visual-vm-to-tomcat-7/). It is a bit on the verbose side, but should help steer you around a number of the problems most people run into.

Comment: +1, this worked for me. The difference between the original question's config and the config that worked for me is this flag: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=50.112.22.47"

Answer (score 3):

Check out the jmx listener on this page.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/listeners.html

It lets you set both the JMX port and the RMI registry port, both of which have to open on your firewall.

Comment: That nearly solved my problem, great and short post - Be careful to check the RMI hostname, on many servers, the external ip is not known to themselves so RMI only binds to some local address.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to catalina_opts: `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=vmhostname`
and ensure that your mac is able to resolve this hostname, e.g.
`nc -v vmhostname 8086`
should succeed in opening the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add actual ip and hostname to /etc/hosts where jstatd is running.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps,

- Download jvisualvm setup from [Download Jvisualvm](http://java.net/projects/visualvm/downloads/download/release132/visualvm_132.zip)
- Unzip this setup and go to bin directory from command line
- Use this command to start the visualvm:

  \bin>visualvm.exe  -J-Dnetbeans.system_socks_proxy=localhost:9998 -J-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
- get the putty setup ,go to installation directory of putty use following command to ssh tunnel to remote system

putty  -D 9998 -load Name_of_the_saved_putty_session

- saved_putty_session should have tunnel to localhost:JMX_port and some_source_port
- now in visualvm UI in Left nav ,right click the remote and "Add remote host" , with public ip of remote host
- Now on this added remote host right click and say "ADD JMX CONNECTION"
- In a connection box say localhost:source_port_provided_in_putty_tunnel
- Click on the ok button and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

So the above worked for me:

`service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://machinedomainname:1099/jmxrmi`

After spending 1/2 day on this. Following all the usual instructions and getting frustrated the above cracked it.

I have a play application deployed in amazon ec2 with the following flags:

```
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<myport>
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
   -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<mymachinedomainname>
```

I have jvisualvm running locally on my mac.

I added a jvisualvm remote host with host name:

```
 <mymachinedomainname>
```

Then added added a jmx connection to this host. 
I tried the recommended

```
service:jmx:rmi://<mymachinedomainname>:<myport>
```

but it would just not connect.

But as soon as i did

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<mymachinedomainname>:<myport>/jmxrmi
```

instead. it connected and works.

No idea why! but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can

```
a) ping <vmhostname>
b) telnet <vmhostname> 8086
```

Note also that you can use IP address instead of `<vmhostname>`

Comment: The VM is up and I can connect. No clue :(
Just tried jconsole, which fails as well.

Comment: Does it mean that you can connect to port 8086 from Mac OS X to your VM?
I am not surprised that jconsole does not work. Both VisualVM and jconsole uses the same code to do JMX connection.
You can try to run tcpdump on your VM and see if there is any communication on port 8086.
Oh and I just noticed tcp6 - does it mean you are using IPv6? If so, this could be a reason, why you cannot connect to Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can wrap it in ipv4 somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `jstatd` process is running on the remote machine which you want to monitor, with required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this option:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
```

Then, connect with

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://machinedomainname:1099/jmxrmi
```

As long as RMI is listening on all interfaces ( ie. 0.0.0.0) then there should be no problem connecting from a remote server as long as the firewall is off (or carefully configured).

Answer (score 0):

I have actually just tackled this problem myself and figured it out.

I would wager that the problem is the RMI connections - you can't predict which ports it will use and so you can't get it to work with a firewall.

The workaround is to use an SSH proxy:

1. SSH to the box where your application is running but use the -D option like this:

   ssh user@remoteHost -D 9999

   This will start a socks proxy on your local machine on port 9999.
2. Open JVisualVM and in the preferences, under 'network' configure it to use a socks proxy at localhost, on port 9999.

If you do the above, you should then be able to connect to the remote machine as normal and since all the RMI traffic is now going over the SSH proxy, it is punched through the firewall and works nicely.

Good luck :-)